Langchain GenericLoader Unsupported mime type when loading java files
I am trying to take a bunch of java files and create an embedding to be used by an LLM.
So want to read java files to create the embeddings in a chroma db.
I have previously managed to do this successfully with pdf files but now I want to use my java code in the embeddings.
I have a method

from langchain_community.document_loaders.generic import GenericLoader
def load_documents():
    loader = GenericLoader.from_filesystem(
        "./path/to/java/files",
        glob="**/*",
        suffixes=[".java"],
        parser=LanguageParser()
    )

I am getting the following error
 main()
  File "/Volumes/SamsungT5/langchain/populate_database.py", line 33, in main
    documents = load_documents()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/path/populate_database.py", line 50, in load_documents
    return loader.load()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_core/document_loaders/base.py", line 29, in load
    return list(self.lazy_load())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_community/document_loaders/generic.py", line 116, in lazy_load
    yield from self.blob_parser.lazy_parse(blob)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_community/document_loaders/parsers/generic.py", line 70, in lazy_parse
    raise ValueError(f"Unsupported mime type: {mimetype}")
ValueError: Unsupported mime type: text/x-java-source

I have no clue why its telling me Unsupported mime type: text/x-java-source. Its my understanding that java file loading is supported.

Edit
I used the DirectoryLoader instead and got done with what I was trying to do.
loader = loader = DirectoryLoader(DATA_PATH, glob="**/*.java",loader_cls=TextLoader,use_multithreading=True)
return loader. Load()



For building an agnostic parser for all code (which is what I think you are trying to do), I recommend using a tree-parser.
